# How can I merge duplicate elements of array while keeping the values combined?

Tags: ruby

I have something like this:

```
prods = [{"1050" => {"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}},
         {"1050" => {"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}},
         {"6650" => {"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}},
         {"6650" => {"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}}]
```

And I would like to merge the duplicates but keep the key value pairs like this

```
prods = [{"1050" => [{"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}, 
                     {"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}}],
         {"6650" => [{"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"},
                     {"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}}]
        ]
```

would this be possible?

Comment: It would be better if the values of all the keys were not the same.

Comment: Does `prods` have to be an Array of Hashes? If `prods` was a Hash to begin with, you might not have this issue...

Comment: P.S. here's a quick conversion to a Hash: `prods.each_with_object({}) {|p, h| k, v = p.to_a[0]; (h[k] ||= []) << v }` ... I think this would be easier to manage than an Array that would allow duplicates to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way among many that you could do that.

**Code**

```
def combine(prods)
  prods.map(&:flatten)
       .each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] << v }
       .map { |k,v| { k=>v } }
end
```

**Examples**

For your value of `prods`:

```
combine(prods)   
  #=> [{"1050"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"},
  #              {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]},
  #    {"6650"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"},
  #    {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]}]
```

Now let's redefine `prods:`

```
prods = [{"1050" => {"keya" => "value1", "keyb" => "value1"}},
         {"1050" => {"keya" => "value2", "keyb" => "value2"}},
         {"6650" => {"keya" => "value3", "keyb" => "value3"}},
         {"6650" => {"keya" => "value4", "keyb" => "value4"}}]
combine(prods)   
  #=> [{"1050"=>[{"keya"=>"value1", "keyb"=>"value1"},
  #              {"keya"=>"value2", "keyb"=>"value2"}]},
  #    {"6650"=>[{"keya"=>"value3", "keyb"=>"value3"},
 #               {"keya"=>"value4", "keyb"=>"value4"}]}]
```

**Explanation**

These are the steps:

```
a = prods.map(&:flatten)
  #=> [["1050", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}],
  #    ["1050", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}],
  #    ["6650", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}],
  #    ["6650", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]] 

h = a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] << v }
  #=> {"1050"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"},
  #             {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}],
  #    "6650"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"},
  #             {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]}
```

Lastly,

```
h.map { |k,v| { k=>v } }
```

produces the result shown above.

In computing `h` [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)'s object is the value of the block variable `h`. Initially, `h` is an empty hash defined as follows:

```
Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}
```

The block gives the hash's default value. This says that if `h` is the hash and `k` is a key to be added to the hash, it's default value is an empty array. The first value of `a` passed to `each_with_object`'s block is:

```
["1050", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]
```

The block variables are therefore assigned as follows:

```
(k,v),h = [["1050", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}], {}]
  #=> [["1050", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}], {}] 
k #=> "1050" 
v #=> {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"} 
h #=> {}
```

and the block calculation is:

```
h[k] << v
```

which is:

```
h["1050"] << {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}
```

Since `h` does not have a key `"1050"`, `h["1050"]` is first assigned its default value, an empty hash, so we have:

```
(h["1050"] = []) << {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}
```

The hash `h` is now:

```
h #=> { "1050"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}] }
```

The next value of `a` is passed to the block, causing the block variables being to be updated as follows:

```
(k,v),h = [["1050", {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}],
           { "1050"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}] }]
k #=> "1050" 
v #=> {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"} 
h #=> {"1050"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]}
```

The block calculation is therefore:

```
h[k] << v
  # h["1050"] << {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}
```

As `h` now has the key `"1050"` (whose value is an array), the default value is not used and the hash `h` becomes

```
h #=> {"1050"=>[{"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"},
  #             {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2"}]}
```

The remaining calculations are performed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = Hash.new {[]}   # this creates a new array when a key doesn't exist
prods.each do |prod|
  prod.each{ |key,val| h[key] = h[key] << val }
end
puts h
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't produce exactly what this question is asking for. If you look at the 'desired output' you will notice how both "1050" and "6650" are individual hashes. Your code produces a hash were both keys are part of the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution:

```
results =
prods.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) do |hash, results|
  key    = hash.keys.first
  values = hash.values

  results[key] += values
end

results = results.map { |k, v| Hash[k, v] }
```

In this solution I just use a hash with a default value to handle the duplicates, then convert to the desired output format.

---

Alternative solution:

```
def find_hash(haystack, needle)
  haystack.index { |hay| hay.keys.first == needle }
end

results =
prods.each_with_object(Array.new) do |hash, results|
  key    = hash.keys.first
  values = hash.values

  idx = find_hash(results, key)

  if idx
    results[idx][key] += values
  else
    results << Hash[key, values]
  end
end
```

Here I try to find if a hash with a specified key already exist and then append to it, otherwise create a new hash and add it to the array.